# How to collect data from python-file to kv-file

Tags: python, kivy

I want to create a Label in my kv-file and the text I want the Label to have is supposed to be collected from my python-file. I have tried to create a function in the python-file that has a variable equal to the string I want the Label to have, but it does not seem to work and I don't know how to do it correctly...

The code below is how my kv-file looks. So it is in the field that says "text:" that I want to collect the data from my python-file.

Hope someone knows how to do!

```
<FirstScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        text:
```

Comment: Why do you like to create a kv file? Do you like to create the UI dynamically or do you want to generate kv files? Like editing the UI and then click a button to generate the kv file?

Comment: If you need to create the kv file, then the following repo should include this part. I haven't studied it yet but it should have that functionality. [kivy-designer](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer).

Comment: I am rather new to Kivy and only watched a few introduction videos about it and using a kv file is the way I have learned to use Kivy so far. Would you say it is better to have everything in python file? The reason I am using Kivy is because I want to code a program that can be used by others on other devices.

Answer (score 1):

In your class `FirstScreen` you can add a `StringProperty` to represent the text.

```
class FirstScreen(Screen):
    mytext = StringProperty('default text')
```

Then, in your `kv` you can use it as:

```
<FirstScreen>:
    Label:
        text: root.mytext
```

Comment: Fantastic!! That works perfectly! Thank you!